# jQuery Clone element

Tags: jquery, clone

I have cloned a element like

```
<div class = "button1"> Button1</div>
<div class = "text1Container">
    <div class="myButton"></div>
</div>
<div class = "text2Container"></div>
```

here my jQuery

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
    $( ".text1Container").clone().appendTo( ".text2Container" );
});
```

so now I want so set click function in "text2Container"
but it did not work

```
//why not working
$(".text2Container .myButton").click(function() {
   alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events for dynamically created html elements. Try this:

```
$(".text2Container").on('click','.myButton',function() {
   alert('hello');
});
```

And you have typo in your code. Replace `button1` with `.button1`:

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
    $( ".text1Container").clone().appendTo( ".text2Container" );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnaUx/2/)

Comment: @UsmanAhmad: To attach an event handler to dynamically created elements. For more details click on link that I shared in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually assigning a click to your `button1`. You are missing the `.` for class selector:

```
$(".button1").click(function () {
    $(".text1Container").clone().appendTo(".text2Container");

    $(".text2Container .myButton").click(function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Note, the `.myButton` binding code has to be in with the `.button1 click` handler. You cannot bind an event to an element that does not exist yet.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCxL3/)